# PHP MYSQL search string everyhwere

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to search a string in table without specifing column?

```
$string = 'hello';

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE all_columns LIKE '%,$string,%' ");
```

and i would like to get one response p.e if there would be two columns in one row which containts same or similar content, but this is not important, i can handle it.

// MY IDEA, NOT SO FAST BUT MIGHT WORK

```
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM particular_table LIMIT = 1");
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $limit = count($data);
    $where_condition = 'WHERE published = 1 AND (';

    $index = 1;
    foreach($data as $key=>$val){
          if($index==$limit){
              $where_condition .= ' '.$key.' LIKE %,'.$string.',%'; 
          } else {
              $where_condition .= ' '.$key.' LIKE %,'.$string.',% OR'; 
          }
          $index++;       
    }
    $where_condition .= ')';

    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM particular_table $where_condition"); 
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($get);
```

It can be stupid and unnecessary so give me your opintion please

Comment: you should probably use mysqli.

Comment: So.. ALL columns have to be `LIKE` a particular value? Or do you mean search all columns and if any of them are `LIKE` a particular value?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: You can also use a dedicated Text-Search engine like Sphinx, which will take data from your MySQL Server and search all the columns for the search string, and will give one result per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution combined with some PHP to search all fields in a **specific** table.

```
include("db_con.php");
//search all fields
$searchphrase = "banan";
$table = "apa303";
$sql_search = "select * from ".$table." where ";
$sql_search_fields = Array();
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table;
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        $colum = $r[0];
        $sql_search_fields[] = $colum." like('%".$searchphrase."%')";
    }

$sql_search .= implode(" OR ", $sql_search_fields);
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql_search);
$out = mysql_num_rows($rs2)."\n";
echo "Number of search hits in $table " . $out;
```

Now adjust the query as you want...

Comment: i just made something similar thank you ill try it ;)